# understanding node module - LTS events

Tags: node.js, npm, tls1.2

I am able to connect to the remote server using this code :

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  //pem p12 files
};

var socket = tls.connect(8000, options, function() {
  console.log('client connected',socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
//code to write data to socket here
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});

socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.on('end', function() {
  console.log('confirm end');
});
```

This is how its documented here . https://node.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/tls/

How can i force the socket to wait for on-data event and not go to on-end before on-data has executed? Is it possible that the server does not emit data and respond with end directly?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to (and you can't) force the order in which the server will emit the events on the client side. By saying `socket.on`, you are registering a callback to an event that will be executed later on once the server emits the corresponding event.

Events do not follow the order in which you specify it in your application (that is just an order in which you are registering those callbacks not the order in which the events will be received and processed).

> Is it possible that the server does not emit data and respond with end directly?

Server can do whatever it is programmed to do. It may not respond at all.